# Converting Object to List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am getting the List of selected Items from WPF Attached Behavioral for ListBox as below:

```
  private void ListBoxSelectionChanged(object param)
    {
        var selectedItems = param;
        SelectedMItems = selectedItems.ToString().Split(',').ToList<string>();
        //Console.WriteLine(selectedItems.ToString());

    }
```

Though it works , is there any other better way.

Comment: What's the actual type? Could it be an `ObservableCollection<string>`?

Comment: Might be better on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This will work fine as long as you're confident the object correctly implements `.ToString()`. You haven't given any details about the object so I won't project any such confidence for you.

Comment: @GrantThomas,@jrajav, object is Collection of selected Items from ListBox , the list box has multiple selection option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectedItems` property is an `IList`, so I'm assuming your object is as well.

In this case, it would be simplest to do one of these two:

```
// If the list already contains strings
SelectedMItems = ((IList)selectedItems).Cast<string>().ToList();

// If the list contains other objects
SelectedMItems = ((IList)selectedItems).Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Why the `Cast<object>()`?  Everything's an object and must implement `ToString()` surely?

Comment: Object Does contain a method for Cast

Comment: The Cast doesn't do anything other than convert the IEnumerable to an IEnumerable<object>, because Select is not available for IEnumerable.

Comment: @Simsons I added a cast. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work, in order to be 'safer':

```
var items = param as ObservableCollection<string>;
```

Or even just an enumerable:

```
var items = param as IEnumerable<string>;
```

Then you have a collection of items proper.

Comment: i would even go as far as doing just `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Simsons Did you examine the thing in the debugger and see what it is?

Comment: Type is object {System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection}

Comment: So, do `... as SelectedItemCollection`, and have a nice strongly typed thing. (: